# Can dogs eat vegetables only?

Tags: dogs

Is it possible for a pet dog to survive with vegetable as food only? If possible, which types of dogs would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Technically it's possible](http://pets.webmd.com/features/vegetarian-diet-dogs-cats), but it requires extreme diligence.  That said, the list specifically calls out certain amino acids (I.E. Taurine) that are found only in animal products, so you could probably get by with a vegetarian (fruit, veggies, fungi, vitamin supplements but *not* only vegetables) diet, if you do it extremely carefully.

To your latter question, the type of dog doesn't really matter; [small tweaks](http://www.petmd.com/blogs/nutritionnuggets/jcoates/2012/feb/nutrition_differences_for_small_toy_large_breeds-12459) may be necessary to combat breed-specific issues.